# Use LOAD DATA INFILE and SELECT INTO OUTFILE in Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, load-data-infile, select-into-outfile

I am testing Google Cloud SQL and I have to test the instructions `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE`.

I understood that the instruction `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` could be used instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but how can it be used in Cloud SQL?

Can the instruction `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE` be used as is?

Thank you Renzo for your answer but when I try to execute the instruction SELECT.. INTO OUTFILE when I am connected to the Cloud SQL instance, I get the following error message:

ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'root'@'%'

I tried to used the instruction LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from my computer connected to Cloud SQL instance on MySQL and it worked. I used a file located on my computer to import CSV data into a table successfully. But I am wondering if I can use a file present in a bucket to do the same...

I try to explain what I need to do:

We are migrating our Website to GCP App Engine/Cloud SQL. We extensively use both instructions LOAD DATA INFILE which select files from a folder "ftp" to load them into the databases. As well, we use the SELECT INTO OUTFILE to export data to CSV files into a folder of our Website. So my concern is to be able to use the same process on App Engine/Cloud SQL.

The difference is that the Website instance and database instance are separated on GCP. Should we use buckets on GCP to replace our folders ? Or should we create folders on App Engine / Cloud SQL instance instead? What is the best solution according to you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page about [Importing data into Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#before_you_begin_2),

> you can also use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement in the **mysql client**, which loads a local file to the database

You can follow a sample steps in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#connect) to start the **mysql client** by connecting to your Cloud SQL instance first through Cloud Shell. After connecting, you will be able to execute the import statement: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

The same steps can be applied for exporting and the syntax `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE` can be used as is. Together with other alternatives, this can be also found on [Exporting data from Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv) :

> Exporting in CSV format is equivalent to running the following SQL statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT <query> INTO OUTFILE ... CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
>         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
>         ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> ```

Once you have executed the operations, it is also advisable to [check their status](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/checking-status-import-export) especially if it is long running or an error has occurred.

Comment: I have tried SELECT <query> INTO OUTFILE while connected to Cloud SQL instance but it does not work, I get the error "Access denied for user".

Comment: Since I cannot use the instruction SELECT...INTO OUTFILE on Cloud SQL, I decided to copy the file to GCP bucket via gcloud instruction or Google API.
Regarding LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, I decided to copy the file from GCP bucket to App Engine temp folder, then use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import data into the database.
I guess it should work, I need to test though...
Thanks